# Running Multiple VMs in VMware workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware

Is it possible to run multiple VMS simultaneously in VMware Workstation Player 15

The documentations seems to suggest No. 
"[VMware Workstation Player is an ideal](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) utility for **running a single virtual machine** on a Windows or Linux PC."

If not VMW Workstation what is the next best- VirtualBox?

Comment: It *can* be done, but perhaps it should not?  I use qemu/kvm and certainly I *can* run more than 1 vm.  However, each active VM consumes quite a bit of resources.  The average desktop PC can run 1+ VM's, but will quickly become bogged down.

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/587768

Comment: If VMware is a must, use it. If not, I would suggest something like qemu. Or look at docker, if you do not require windows etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Simply open the virtual machine from the vmware-workstation player interface. If you want to open another instance simply open a new instance of vmware-workstation player. I suggest the pro version though it will help you properly achieve what you want.